String Comparison with non-printing characters
I need to compare two strings composed by joining various substrings, taking into account the substrings themselves - i.e. the substrings are separated by a separator within the string itself.
I can easily solve the comparison using the "/" separator, but the thing is that those substrings can contain any character (e.g., "/"). So I tried to use a non-printable character, whose code is less than 32 - I settled with character 31.
But now, the comparison returns different results depending on the comparison mode:
dim string1$, string2$, sep$
sep = Chr(31)
string1 = "11" & sep & "1"
string2 = "1" & sep & "11"
comp = StrComp(string1, string2, vbBinaryCompare)   ' returns  1, i.e. string1 > string2 - right
comp = StrComp(string1, string2, vbTextCompare)     ' returns -1, i.e. string1 < string2 - wrong

I could take note and do the binary comparison, but I need to compare in text mode.
Since 31 is lower than any printable character's code, and since there is no lower-case or upper case of Chr(31) (or is it?), I would expect both comparison types to return string1 > string2.  Why is this happening, what am I misunderstanding?

Have you considered using multiple printable characters that don't appear in any string as a separator? (something like /\/\/\  maybe?)

According to MS, "A Binary comparison compares the numeric Unicode value of each character in each string. A Text comparison compares each Unicode character based on its lexical meaning in the current culture." Not sure what the "lexical meaning" of Chr(31) is, but it appears it is not what you expect.

@001 Point taken. However, my expectation was based on Chr(31) having no lexical meaning in my culture. I wonder if it has in any other culture :)
Would anyone expect anything else?

It seems that MS didn't document the exact behavior of Text comparison when it comes to non-printable characters - at least I can't find anything.
You can create your own little compare function so that you can use Text comparison but non-printable characters. The following function will split the strings into pieces (by the specified separator) and compare the pieces one by one:
Function myStrComp(s1 As String, s2 As String, separator As String, Optional compareMethod As Long = vbTextCompare) As Long
    Dim s1Arr() As String, s2Arr() As String
    Dim i As Long, maxIndex As Long
    
    If StrComp(s1, s2, compareMethod) = 0 Then Exit Function   ' Strings are identical
    s1Arr = Split(s1, separator)
    s2Arr = Split(s2, separator)
    maxIndex = IIf(UBound(s1Arr) < UBound(s2Arr), UBound(s1Arr), UBound(s2Arr))
    
    ' compare the pieces.
    For i = 1 To maxIndex
        myStrComp = StrComp(s1Arr(i), s2Arr(i), compareMethod)
        If myStrComp <> 0 Then Exit Function
    Next i
    
    ' All pieces are identical but one string contains extra piece
    myStrComp = IIf(UBound(s1Arr) < UBound(s2Arr), 1, -1)
End Function

Testing it:
Dim string1$, string2$, sep$
sep = Chr(31)
string1 = "11" & sep & "1"
string2 = "1" & sep & "11"

Debug.Print "Bin:" & myStrComp(string1, string2, vbBinaryCompare)
Debug.Print "Txt:" & myStrComp(string1, string2, vbTextCompare) 
Debug.Print "Txt:" & myStrComp(string1, string1, vbTextCompare)
Debug.Print "Txt:" & myStrComp(string1, string1 & sep & "111", vbTextCompare)

results in
Bin:-1
Txt:-1
Txt:0
Txt:1


Nice solution, thank you. It extends the StrComp function, making it work as expected - although 001 above might say not everyone expects this outcome :)
I came up with another solution - binaryCompare over Lcase(strings). Your solution is more general and elegant, but one needs to know the separator beforehand; mine is uglier, but I think is a bit faster and the separator doesn't matter.
Nonetheless, the question remains (unanswered?): why this behaviour? I hate partially documented functions.
